# WiFi periodically switches between 2.4GHz and 5GHz

Tags: wireless, network-manager, wpa-supplicant

I noticed janks and disconnections during online conference call and here is what I found:

**[Issue]**

```
bsdson@HP-EliteBook-840-G7:~/Desktop/0911_wifi_disconnect$ grep "kernel.*disconnect" syslog
16:45:21.016349 kernel: [ 4524.287591] wlp0s20f3: disconnect from AP 40:9b:cd:a8:27:54 for new auth to 40:9b:cd:a8:27:52     // #1
16:45:53.552334 kernel: [ 4556.823065] wlp0s20f3: disconnect from AP 40:9b:cd:a8:27:52 for new auth to 40:9b:cd:a8:27:54    // #2
16:46:04.748513 kernel: [ 4568.018741] wlp0s20f3: disconnect from AP 40:9b:cd:a8:27:54 for new auth to 40:9b:cd:a8:27:52      // #3
16:46:43.500378 kernel: [ 4606.770683] wlp0s20f3: disconnect from AP 40:9b:cd:a8:27:52 for new auth to 40:9b:cd:a8:27:54    // #4
16:49:32.908352 kernel: [ 4776.176031] wlp0s20f3: disconnect from AP 40:9b:cd:a8:27:54 for new auth to 40:9b:cd:a8:27:52     // #5
16:50:05.472390 kernel: [ 4808.740814] wlp0s20f3: disconnect from AP 40:9b:cd:a8:27:52 for new auth to 40:9b:cd:a8:27:54     // #6
```

**[Environment]**

Ubuntu 23.04 on HP EliteBook 840 G7.

WiFi router: D-LINK DIR-X1860 with latest firmware.

The laptop is on the same floor as the WiFi router, distanced about 6 meters.

WiFi driver: iwlwifi

wpa_supplicant v2.10

NetworkManager 1.42.4-1ubuntu2

**[Log]**

Here is the detailed log just before the #4 disconnect/reconnect.

```
16:46:06.683123 wpa_supplicant[812]: EAPOL: startWhen --> 0
16:46:06.683390 wpa_supplicant[812]: EAPOL: disable timer tick
16:46:10.083330 NetworkManager[810]: <debug> [1694594770.0825] ndisc-lndp[0x555fe940e980,"wlp0s20f3"]: processing libndp events
16:46:15.153790 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
16:46:15.248310 NetworkManager[810]: <debug> [1694594775.2476] ndisc-lndp[0x555fe940e980,"wlp0s20f3"]: processing libndp events
16:46:15.354261 NetworkManager[810]: <trace> [1694594775.3540] device[b7bdd2811ce4ce7d] (wlp0s20f3): connectivity: [IPv4] periodic-check: re-scheduled in 299999 milliseconds (300 seconds interval)
16:46:15.354648 NetworkManager[810]: <trace> [1694594775.3541] device[b7bdd2811ce4ce7d] (wlp0s20f3): connectivity: [IPv4] start check (seq:113, periodic-check)
16:46:15.354935 NetworkManager[810]: <debug> [1694594775.3544] connectivity: (wlp0s20f3,IPv4,113) start request to 'http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./' (try resolving 'connectivity-check.ubuntu.com.' using systemd-resolved)
16:46:15.710639 NetworkManager[810]: <trace> [1694594775.7103] connectivity: (wlp0s20f3,IPv4,113) set curl resolve list to 'connectivity-check.ubuntu.com.:80:35.232.111.17,34.122.121.32,91.189.91.48,35.224.170.84,185.125.190.49,91.189.91.49,185.125.190.18,185.125.190.17,185.125.190.48'
16:46:16.119116 NetworkManager[810]: <debug> [1694594776.1187] connectivity: (wlp0s20f3,IPv4,113) check completed: FULL; status header found
16:46:16.119538 NetworkManager[810]: <trace> [1694594776.1188] device[b7bdd2811ce4ce7d] (wlp0s20f3): connectivity: [IPv4] complete check (seq:113, state:FULL)
16:46:16.119847 NetworkManager[810]: <trace> [1694594776.1188] device[b7bdd2811ce4ce7d] (wlp0s20f3): connectivity: [IPv4] periodic-check: re-scheduled in 299234 milliseconds (300 seconds interval)
16:46:25.029663 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Event message available
16:46:25.030232 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: BSS Event 59 (NL80211_CMD_FRAME) received for wlp0s20f3
16:46:25.030488 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: MLME event 59 (NL80211_CMD_FRAME) on wlp0s20f3(32:b4:d3:f9:0f:18) A1=32:b4:d3:f9:0f:18 A2=40:9b:cd:a8:27:52
16:46:25.030725 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: MLME event frame - hexdump(len=79): d0 40 24 00 32 b4 d3 f9 0f 18 40 9b cd a8 27 52 40 9b cd a8 27 52 20 03 05 00 da 00 00 26 30 da 00 05 80 28 00 00 14 00 01 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 08 70 6c 61 6e 6b 74 6f 6e 01 02 00 00 02 01 01 0a 0d 00 01 2d 30 32 36 3d 46 7f bf c0 c3 dd
16:46:25.030943 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Frame event
16:46:25.031143 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: RX frame da=32:b4:d3:f9:0f:18 sa=40:9b:cd:a8:27:52 bssid=40:9b:cd:a8:27:52 freq=2422 ssi_signal=-46 fc=0x40d0 seq_ctrl=0x320 stype=13 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) len=79
16:46:25.031321 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Event RX_MGMT (18) received
16:46:25.031453 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Received Action frame: SA=40:9b:cd:a8:27:52 Category=5 DataLen=54 freq=2422 MHz
16:46:25.031622 wpa_supplicant[812]: Measurement request type 5 token 218
16:46:25.031830 wpa_supplicant[812]: Beacon request: No valid channels
16:46:25.032007 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Send Action frame (ifindex=2, freq=2422 MHz wait=0 ms no_cck=0 offchanok=1)
16:46:25.032194 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: CMD_FRAME freq=2422 wait=0 no_cck=0 no_ack=0 offchanok=1
16:46:25.032427 wpa_supplicant[812]: CMD_FRAME - hexdump(len=32): d0 00 00 00 40 9b cd a8 27 52 32 b4 d3 f9 0f 18 40 9b cd a8 27 52 00 00 05 01 da 27 03 da 04 05
16:46:25.032648 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Frame TX command accepted; cookie 0x13
16:46:25.032846 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Event message available
16:46:25.033049 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Ignored event 60 (NL80211_CMD_FRAME_TX_STATUS) for foreign interface (ifindex 2 wdev 0x0)
16:46:25.033259 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Drv Event 60 (NL80211_CMD_FRAME_TX_STATUS) received for wlp0s20f3
16:46:25.033450 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: MLME event 60 (NL80211_CMD_FRAME_TX_STATUS) on wlp0s20f3(32:b4:d3:f9:0f:18) A1=40:9b:cd:a8:27:52 A2=32:b4:d3:f9:0f:18
16:46:25.033669 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: MLME event frame - hexdump(len=32): d0 00 00 00 40 9b cd a8 27 52 32 b4 d3 f9 0f 18 40 9b cd a8 27 52 00 00 05 01 da 27 03 da 04 05
16:46:25.033853 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Frame TX status event A1=40:9b:cd:a8:27:52 stype=13 cookie=0x13 ack=1
16:46:25.034029 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Frame TX status: cookie=0x13 (match) (ack=1)
16:46:25.034229 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Event TX_STATUS (16) received
16:46:25.034417 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: EVENT_TX_STATUS dst=40:9b:cd:a8:27:52 type=0 stype=13
16:46:25.034594 wpa_supplicant[812]: Off-channel: Ignore Action TX status - no pending operation


// Let's check this one    VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV


16:46:43.324962 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Event message available
16:46:43.325648 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: BSS Event 59 (NL80211_CMD_FRAME) received for wlp0s20f3
16:46:43.325895 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: MLME event 59 (NL80211_CMD_FRAME) on wlp0s20f3(32:b4:d3:f9:0f:18) A1=32:b4:d3:f9:0f:18 A2=40:9b:cd:a8:27:52
16:46:43.326062 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: MLME event frame - hexdump(len=49): d0 40 24 00 32 b4 d3 f9 0f 18 40 9b cd a8 27 52 40 9b cd a8 27 52 30 03 0a 07 26 03 00 00 c8 34 10 40 9b cd a8 27 54 00 00 00 00 73 28 00 03 01 ff
16:46:43.326191 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Frame event
16:46:43.326323 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: RX frame da=32:b4:d3:f9:0f:18 sa=40:9b:cd:a8:27:52 bssid=40:9b:cd:a8:27:52 freq=2422 ssi_signal=-46 fc=0x40d0 seq_ctrl=0x330 stype=13 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) len=49
16:46:43.326450 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Event RX_MGMT (18) received
16:46:43.326569 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Received Action frame: SA=40:9b:cd:a8:27:52 Category=10 DataLen=24 freq=2422 MHz
16:46:43.326700 wpa_supplicant[812]: WNM: RX action 7 from 40:9b:cd:a8:27:52
16:46:43.326825 wpa_supplicant[812]: WNM: BSS Transition Management Request: dialog_token=38 request_mode=0x3 disassoc_timer=0 validity_interval=200
16:46:43.326951 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: WNM: Preferred List Available
16:46:43.327079 wpa_supplicant[812]: WNM: Neighbor report tag 52
16:46:43.327231 wpa_supplicant[812]: WNM: Subelement id=3 len=1
16:46:43.327379 wpa_supplicant[812]: WNM: BSS Transition Candidate List
16:46:43.327548 wpa_supplicant[812]: 0: 40:9b:cd:a8:27:54 info=0x0 op_class=115 chan=40 phy=0 pref=255 freq=5200
16:46:43.327653 wpa_supplicant[812]: WNM: Candidate list valid for 20480 ms
16:46:43.327752 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: WNM: Fetch current scan results from the driver for checking transition candidates
16:46:43.327849 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Received scan results (1 BSSes)
16:46:43.327957 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Scan results indicate BSS status with 40:9b:cd:a8:27:52 as associated
16:46:43.328071 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: WNM: No transition candidate matches existing scan results
16:46:43.328172 wpa_supplicant[812]: WNM: Scan 1 frequencies based on transition candidate list
16:46:43.328360 wpa_supplicant[812]: WNM: Scan only for a specific BSSID since there is only a single candidate 40:9b:cd:a8:27:54
16:46:43.328556 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Setting scan request: 0.000000 sec
16:46:43.328693 wpa_supplicant[812]: Scan SSID - hexdump(len=8): 70 6c 61 6e 6b 74 6f 6e
16:46:43.328872 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Starting AP scan for wildcard SSID
16:46:43.329034 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS: Building WPS IE for Probe Request
16:46:43.329216 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS:  * Version (hardcoded 0x10)
16:46:43.329380 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS:  * Request Type
16:46:43.329524 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS:  * Config Methods (3148)
16:46:43.329710 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS:  * UUID-E
16:46:43.329867 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS:  * Primary Device Type
16:46:43.330031 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS:  * RF Bands (3)
16:46:43.330180 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS:  * Association State
16:46:43.330357 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS:  * Configuration Error (0)
16:46:43.330517 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS:  * Device Password ID (0)
16:46:43.330691 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS:  * Manufacturer
16:46:43.330859 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS:  * Model Name
16:46:43.331018 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS:  * Model Number
16:46:43.331177 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS:  * Device Name
16:46:43.331348 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS:  * Version2 (0x20)
16:46:43.331547 wpa_supplicant[812]: P2P: * P2P IE header
16:46:43.331764 wpa_supplicant[812]: P2P: * Capability dev=25 group=00
16:46:43.331989 wpa_supplicant[812]: P2P: * Listen Channel: Regulatory Class 81 Channel 6
16:46:43.332620 NetworkManager[810]: <trace> [1694594803.3318] sup-iface[02e0773285906816,0,wlp0s20f3]: scanning: yes (plain property)
16:46:43.332940 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Optimize scan based on previously generated frequency list
16:46:43.333102 NetworkManager[810]: <trace> [1694594803.3319] sup-iface[02e0773285906816,0,wlp0s20f3]: scanning: yes
16:46:43.333755 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Scan a previously specified BSSID 40:9b:cd:a8:27:54
16:46:43.333966 NetworkManager[810]: <debug> [1694594803.3319] device[b7bdd2811ce4ce7d] (wlp0s20f3): wifi-scan: scanning-state: scanning
16:46:43.334300 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Add radio work 'scan'@0x55db54e862c0
16:46:43.334538 NetworkManager[810]: <trace> [1694594803.3320] device[b7bdd2811ce4ce7d] (wlp0s20f3): wifi-scan: kickoff: don't scan (periodic scan currently not allowed)
16:46:43.334838 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: First radio work item in the queue - schedule start immediately
16:46:43.335070 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Starting radio work 'scan'@0x55db54e862c0 after 0.000042 second wait
16:46:43.335288 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: nl80211: scan request
16:46:43.335473 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Scan SSID plankton
16:46:43.335672 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Scan SSID 
16:46:43.335886 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Scan extra IEs - hexdump(len=150): 7f 0b 04 00 4a 02 01 40 40 40 00 01 20 dd 69 00 50 f2 04 10 4a 00 01 10 10 3a 00 01 00 10 08 00 02 31 48 10 47 00 10 e6 b4 50 8f 1f 80 53 a5 81 92 23 bc 71 c4 8e ca 10 54 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 3c 00 01 03 10 02 00 02 00 00 10 09 00 02 00 00 10 12 00 02 00 00 10 21 00 01 20 10 23 00 01 20 10 24 00 01 20 10 11 00 01 20 10 49 00 06 00 37 2a 00 01 20 dd 11 50 6f 9a 09 02 02 00 25 00 06 05 00 58 58 04 51 06 72 00 dd 07 50 6f 9a 16 03 01 03
16:46:43.336073 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Scan frequency 5200 MHz
16:46:43.336201 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Scan for a specific BSSID: 40:9b:cd:a8:27:54
16:46:43.336340 wpa_supplicant[812]: Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds



16:46:43.336481 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Event message available
16:46:43.336595 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Ignored event 33 (NL80211_CMD_TRIGGER_SCAN) for foreign interface (ifindex 2 wdev 0x0)
16:46:43.336706 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Drv Event 33 (NL80211_CMD_TRIGGER_SCAN) received for wlp0s20f3
16:46:43.336940 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: nl80211: Scan trigger
16:46:43.337053 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Event SCAN_STARTED (47) received
16:46:43.337153 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Own scan request started a scan in 0.000081 seconds
16:46:43.337265 wpa_supplicant[812]: dbus: flush_object_timeout_handler: Timeout - sending changed properties of object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
16:46:43.396783 wpa_supplicant[812]: RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=2 ifname=wlp0s20f3 wext ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x11043 ([UP][RUNNING][LOWER_UP])
16:46:43.397065 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Event message available
16:46:43.397253 NetworkManager[810]: <trace> [1694594803.3966] platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 0: ignore
16:46:43.397495 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Ignored event 34 (NL80211_CMD_NEW_SCAN_RESULTS) for foreign interface (ifindex 2 wdev 0x0)
16:46:43.397652 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Drv Event 34 (NL80211_CMD_NEW_SCAN_RESULTS) received for wlp0s20f3
16:46:43.397861 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: nl80211: New scan results available
16:46:43.398003 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Scan probed for SSID 'plankton'
16:46:43.398131 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Scan probed for SSID ''
16:46:43.398260 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Scan included frequencies: 5200
16:46:43.398437 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received
16:46:43.398647 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Scan completed in 0.070428 seconds
16:46:43.398876 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Received scan results (3 BSSes)
16:46:43.399075 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Scan results indicate BSS status with 40:9b:cd:a8:27:52 as associated
16:46:43.399211 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: BSS: Start scan result update 37
16:46:43.399340 wpa_supplicant[812]: BSS: last_scan_res_used=3/32
16:46:43.399477 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: New scan results available (own=1 ext=0)
16:46:43.399634 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: WNM: Process scan results for BSS Transition Management
16:46:43.399829 wpa_supplicant[812]: WNM: Current BSS 40:9b:cd:a8:27:52 RSSI -49



// firstly mentioned 27:54 as preferred AP.
16:46:43.399965 wpa_supplicant[812]: WNM: Found an acceptable preferred transition candidate BSS 40:9b:cd:a8:27:54 (RSSI -66)
16:46:43.400142 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: WNM: Transition to BSS 40:9b:cd:a8:27:54 based on BSS Transition Management Request (old BSSID 40:9b:cd:a8:27:52 after_new_scan=1)
16:46:43.400344 wpa_supplicant[812]: WNM: Sending successful BSS Transition Management Response
16:46:43.400566 wpa_supplicant[812]: WNM: Send BSS Transition Management Response to 40:9b:cd:a8:27:52 dialog_token=38 status=0 reason=0 delay=0
16:46:43.400720 wpa_supplicant[812]: WNM: Add candidate list to BSS Transition Management Response frame
16:46:43.400871 wpa_supplicant[812]: WNM: BSS Transition Management Response candidate list - hexdump(len=47): 0a 08 26 00 00 40 9b cd a8 27 54 34 10 40 9b cd a8 27 54 92 08 00 00 80 28 09 03 01 ff 34 10 40 9b cd a8 27 52 c2 08 00 00 51 03 09 03 01 fe
16:46:43.401011 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Send Action frame (ifindex=2, freq=2422 MHz wait=0 ms no_cck=0 offchanok=1)
16:46:43.401125 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: CMD_FRAME freq=2422 wait=0 no_cck=0 no_ack=0 offchanok=1
16:46:43.401227 wpa_supplicant[812]: CMD_FRAME - hexdump(len=71): d0 00 00 00 40 9b cd a8 27 52 32 b4 d3 f9 0f 18 40 9b cd a8 27 52 00 00 0a 08 26 00 00 40 9b cd a8 27 54 34 10 40 9b cd a8 27 54 92 08 00 00 80 28 09 03 01 ff 34 10 40 9b cd a8 27 52 c2 08 00 00 51 03 09 03 01 fe
16:46:43.401338 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Frame TX command accepted; cookie 0x14
16:46:43.401447 wpa_supplicant[812]: WNM: Issuing connect
16:46:43.401550 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Considering connect request: reassociate: 1  selected: 40:9b:cd:a8:27:54  bssid: 40:9b:cd:a8:27:52  pending: 00:00:00:00:00:00  wpa_state: COMPLETED  ssid=0x55db54eccc00  current_ssid=0x55db54eccc00



// request to associate with 27:54
16:46:43.401660 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Request association with 40:9b:cd:a8:27:54
16:46:43.401776 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Re-association to the same ESS
16:46:43.401894 wpa_supplicant[812]: TDLS: TDLS is allowed in the target BSS
16:46:43.402020 wpa_supplicant[812]: TDLS: TDLS channel switch allowed in the target BSS
16:46:43.402131 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Abort an ongoing scan
16:46:43.402287 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Abort scan
16:46:43.402396 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Abort scan failed: ret=-2 (No such file or directory)
16:46:43.402492 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Add radio work 'sme-connect'@0x55db54ec4cc0
16:46:43.402597 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Radio work 'scan'@0x55db54e862c0 done in 0.072909 seconds
16:46:43.402712 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: radio_work_free('scan'@0x55db54e862c0): num_active_works --> 0
16:46:43.402826 wpa_supplicant[812]: p2p-dev-wlp0s20: Updating scan results from sibling
16:46:43.402934 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Received scan results (3 BSSes)
16:46:43.403031 wpa_supplicant[812]: p2p-dev-wlp0s20: BSS: Start scan result update 29
16:46:43.403141 wpa_supplicant[812]: BSS: last_scan_res_used=3/32
16:46:43.403247 wpa_supplicant[812]: p2p-dev-wlp0s20: New scan results available (own=0 ext=0)
16:46:43.403361 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS: AP[0] 40:9b:cd:a8:27:54 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago bssid_ignore=0
16:46:43.403472 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS: AP[1] 40:9b:cd:a8:27:52 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago bssid_ignore=0
16:46:43.403577 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS: AP[2] c0:06:c3:d7:0f:c6 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago bssid_ignore=0
16:46:43.403680 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS: AP[3] c0:06:c3:d7:0f:c7 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago bssid_ignore=0
16:46:43.403782 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS: AP[4] d8:0d:17:e8:c9:f3 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago bssid_ignore=0
16:46:43.403887 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS: AP[5] 5c:92:5e:4b:c7:e0 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago bssid_ignore=0
16:46:43.404001 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS: AP[6] 28:87:ba:e2:d4:7e type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago bssid_ignore=0
16:46:43.404108 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS: AP[7] 54:b7:bd:e2:b5:70 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago bssid_ignore=0
16:46:43.404206 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS: AP[8] 1c:13:86:d2:27:ed type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago bssid_ignore=0
16:46:43.404333 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS: AP[9] f4:28:53:f8:cf:94 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago bssid_ignore=0
16:46:43.404469 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS: AP[10] f4:49:55:10:50:71 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago bssid_ignore=0
16:46:43.404585 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS: AP[11] a4:39:b3:8f:24:f0 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago bssid_ignore=0
16:46:43.404693 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPS: AP[12] 78:54:2e:5c:4b:da type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago bssid_ignore=0
16:46:43.404804 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Starting radio work 'sme-connect'@0x55db54ec4cc0 after 0.000387 second wait
16:46:43.404911 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: WPA: clearing own WPA/RSN IE
16:46:43.405021 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: RSN: clearing own RSNXE
16:46:43.405119 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Automatic auth_alg selection: 0x1
16:46:43.405222 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Using SAE auth_alg
16:46:43.405320 wpa_supplicant[812]: RSN: PMKSA cache search - network_ctx=0x55db54eccc00 try_opportunistic=0 akmp=0x0
16:46:43.405431 wpa_supplicant[812]: RSN: Search for BSSID 40:9b:cd:a8:27:54
16:46:43.405567 wpa_supplicant[812]: RSN: PMKSA cache entry found - PMKID - hexdump(len=16): 98 c6 c6 07 a2 97 5c 94 9d fa 8e d4 56 a1 b7 4d
16:46:43.405674 wpa_supplicant[812]: RSN: Trying to use cached PMKSA
16:46:43.405785 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: RSN: using IEEE 802.11i/D9.0
16:46:43.405901 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: WPA: Selected cipher suites: group 16 pairwise 16 key_mgmt 1026 proto 2
16:46:43.405998 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: WPA: Selected mgmt group cipher 32
16:46:43.406094 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: WPA: clearing AP WPA IE
16:46:43.406208 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPA: set AP RSN IE - hexdump(len=32): 30 1e 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 04 02 00 00 0f ac 02 00 0f ac 08 80 00 00 00 00 0f ac 06
16:46:43.406309 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: WPA: clearing AP RSNXE
16:46:43.406406 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: WPA: AP group 0x10 network profile group 0x18; available group 0x10
16:46:43.406505 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: WPA: using GTK CCMP
16:46:43.406600 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: WPA: AP pairwise 0x10 network profile pairwise 0x18; available pairwise 0x10
16:46:43.406705 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: WPA: using PTK CCMP
16:46:43.406803 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: WPA: AP key_mgmt 0x402 network profile key_mgmt 0xd42; available key_mgmt 0x402
16:46:43.406913 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: RSN: using KEY_MGMT SAE
16:46:43.407001 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: WPA: AP mgmt_group_cipher 0x20 network profile mgmt_group_cipher 0x0; available mgmt_group_cipher 0x20
16:46:43.407097 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: WPA: using MGMT group cipher AES-128-CMAC
16:46:43.407198 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPA: Set own WPA IE default - hexdump(len=44): 30 2a 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 08 80 00 01 00 98 c6 c6 07 a2 97 5c 94 9d fa 8e d4 56 a1 b7 4d 00 0f ac 06
16:46:43.407313 wpa_supplicant[812]: RSN: Set own RSNXE default - hexdump(len=3): f4 01 20
16:46:43.407413 wpa_supplicant[812]: PSK (set in config) - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
16:46:43.407527 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPA: Set PMK based on external data - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
16:46:43.407628 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: SME: Selected AP supports MFP: require MFP
16:46:43.407733 wpa_supplicant[812]: RRM: Determining whether RRM can be used - device support: 0x19
16:46:43.407839 wpa_supplicant[812]: RRM: Adding RRM IE to Association Request
16:46:43.407939 wpa_supplicant[812]: Added supported operating classes IE - hexdump(len=19): 3b 11 80 51 53 54 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a 7b 7c 7d 7e 7f
16:46:43.408048 wpa_supplicant[812]: RSN: PMKSA cache search - network_ctx=0x55db54eccc00 try_opportunistic=0 akmp=0x400
16:46:43.408157 wpa_supplicant[812]: RSN: Search for BSSID 40:9b:cd:a8:27:54
16:46:43.408260 wpa_supplicant[812]: RSN: PMKSA cache entry found - PMKID - hexdump(len=16): 98 c6 c6 07 a2 97 5c 94 9d fa 8e d4 56 a1 b7 4d
16:46:43.408420 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: PMKSA cache entry found - try to use PMKSA caching instead of new SAE authentication
16:46:43.408560 wpa_supplicant[812]: WPA: Set PMK based on current PMKSA - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
16:46:43.408672 wpa_supplicant[812]: EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=0
16:46:43.408785 wpa_supplicant[812]: EAPOL: External notification - EAP fail=0
16:46:43.408884 wpa_supplicant[812]: EAPOL: External notification - portControl=Auto
16:46:43.408982 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Cancelling scan request
16:46:43.409102 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: SME: Trying to authenticate with 40:9b:cd:a8:27:54 (SSID='plankton' freq=5200 MHz)
16:46:43.409229 wpa_supplicant[812]: EAPOL: External notification - portValid=0
16:46:43.409339 wpa_supplicant[812]: EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state DISCONNECTED
16:46:43.409450 wpa_supplicant[812]: EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
16:46:43.409538 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Set supplicant port unauthorized for 40:9b:cd:a8:27:52
16:46:43.409650 wpa_supplicant[812]: EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state INITIALIZE
16:46:43.409755 wpa_supplicant[812]: EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state CONNECTING
16:46:43.409874 wpa_supplicant[812]: EAPOL: enable timer tick
16:46:43.409976 wpa_supplicant[812]: EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state IDLE
16:46:43.410085 wpa_supplicant[812]: wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=2 (wlp0s20f3) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0 key_flag=0x10
16:46:43.410197 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: DEL_KEY
16:46:43.410302 wpa_supplicant[812]:    broadcast key
16:46:43.410414 wpa_supplicant[812]: wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=2 (wlp0s20f3) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0 key_flag=0x10
16:46:43.410516 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: DEL_KEY
16:46:43.410607 wpa_supplicant[812]:    broadcast key
16:46:43.464817 wpa_supplicant[812]: wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=2 (wlp0s20f3) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=4 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0 key_flag=0x10
16:46:43.465125 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: DEL_KEY
16:46:43.465272 wpa_supplicant[812]:    broadcast key
16:46:43.496861 wpa_supplicant[812]: wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=2 (wlp0s20f3) alg=0 addr=0x55db54ece890 key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0 key_flag=0x20
16:46:43.497156 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: DEL_KEY
16:46:43.497312 wpa_supplicant[812]:    addr=40:9b:cd:a8:27:54
16:46:43.497476 wpa_supplicant[812]:    pairwise key
16:46:43.497607 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: State: COMPLETED -> AUTHENTICATING
16:46:43.497749 wpa_supplicant[812]: bgscan: Deinitializing module 'simple'
16:46:43.497905 wpa_supplicant[812]: nl80211: Signal monitor threshold=0 hysteresis=0
16:46:43.498034 wpa_supplicant[812]: WMM AC: WMM AC is disabled
16:46:43.498154 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Determining shared radio frequencies (max len 2)
16:46:43.498286 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: Shared frequencies (len=1): completed iteration
16:46:43.498426 wpa_supplicant[812]: wlp0s20f3: freq[0]: 2422, flags=0x1
16:46:43.498653 wpa_supplicant[812]: P2P: Add operating class 81
16:46:43.498859 wpa_supplicant[812]: P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=13): 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d
16:46:43.499050 NetworkManager[810]: <trace> [1694594803.4985] platform-linux: event-notification: RTM_NEWLINK, flags 0, seq 0: 2: wlp0s20f3 <UP;broadcast,multicast,up> mtu 1500 arp 1 wifi? not-init addrgenmode none addr 32:B4:D3:F9:0F:18 permaddr E4:5E:37:32:30:DE brd FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF rx:168093,160314872 tx:88262,30083925
16:46:43.499233 wpa_supplicant[812]: P2P: Add operating class 115
16:46:43.499417 NetworkManager[810]: <debug> [1694594803.4987] platform: (wlp0s20f3) signal: link changed: 2: wlp0s20f3 <UP;broadcast,multicast,up> mtu 1500 arp 1 wifi? init addrgenmode none addr 32:B4:D3:F9:0F:18 permaddr E4:5E:37:32:30:DE brd FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF driver iwlwifi rx:168093,160314872 tx:88262,30083925
16:46:43.499855 wpa_supplicant[812]: P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30


16:46:43.500378 kernel: [ 4606.770683] wlp0s20f3: disconnect from AP 40:9b:cd:a8:27:52 for new auth to 40:9b:cd:a8:27:54    // #4
```

**[things I found, but not sure if relevant]**

- Someone mentioned Power Saving mode. And, yes, Ubuntu is in power saving mode, but I do want to stay in this mode.
- MAC Randomization: Tried enable and disable, both cases suffer from disconnection/reconnection.
- Tried to edit my connection to 5GHz or 2.4GHz only. This avoids the disconnection, but I still want to know the problem and a better solution.
- Someone said NetworkManager used to scan for better connection periodically a long time ago, but now dispatched this work to wpa_supplicant. This sounds like my case, but the period seems not right. See below for more info: https://askubuntu.com/a/1348319/368231

Wondering if anyone knows more about this and if any similar cases out there, since the environment seems to be quite normal... Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am no expert here but does your router support "band steering"? Is your SSID for 2,4 ghz and 5 ghz the same or diffferent? I would create different ssids, and just autoconnect to the 5 ghz. This is perhaps the easiest solution to setup. It can be that the 2,4 ghz has better signal quality than 5 ghz although it is slower in bandwith and speed.